# Can the OP of a locked answer still edit it?

Tags: support, edits, locked-answers

There was this [edit war](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3826/41775) and then a diamond moderator locked the answer to stop the edit war.

Can the OP still edit the answer? Or is everyone, (including OP) except for diamond moderators prevented from editing the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP can't - unless they've got a diamond. And sometimes that's also the purpose of such a lock - to stop OP rolling back any edits or vandalizing the post.

Comment: I had a mistake in the question, I fixed it now. By "OP" I meant the *answerer*, obviously. But I'm sure you realized that, and your answer is probably still applicable.

Comment: @Fiks Yes - that's exactly how I've understood it :)

Comment: You can take a look at [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/789999/most-rolled-back-posts): The greatest rollback war generated 740 rollbacks in total.

Comment: @iDeb oh, that must have involved an awful amount of mad mouse-clicking

Comment: @nicael Probably no. The 740 rollbacks happened in a time spam of two days before a moderator stepped in and locked it.

Comment: Can diamond mods edit locked posts, or do they have to unlock it first? I think I've seen posts get unlocked for a few seconds and then locked again after a minor edit was made by the same person as the one doing the unlocking/locking.